# Restkit Terminal Issue

Tags: ios, xcode4.3, restkit

I am getting the following error when I try to add RestKit code to a terminal.  What am I missing?

```
git submodule add git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git RestKit
Cloning into RestKit...
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Operation timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Operation timed out)
Clone of 'git://github.com/RestKit/RestKit.git' into submodule path 'RestKit' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong - your computer is timing out while trying to connect to github.com. There can be many reasons for this, but I am assuming that you do have a working internet connection.  Maybe a firewall is blocking TCP port 9418 which is used for the git protocol. Try to use the http protocol instead, if you can’t reconfigure your firewall.

Comment: ok I'll try that. Do you have a tutorial for the html protocol?